# Order: To get comment field details from DB in magento 2

Tags: php, sales-order, magento2.2

In admin panel **Sales->Orders** section, while **viewing** the **order**, It **show** order **information** like below
[image]

I **need** to **fetch** the **comment** details from **core table** (**sale_order_status_history**).and want to **show** in **frontend**. Please provide a solution to get comment field details and what are the files needed to achieve this.

For reference the image is below,
[image]

I have created **Block file** but it **returns empty page**

```
<?php

namespace XXX\SalesOrder\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory as OrderFactory;

class Hello extends Template
{

    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, OrderFactory $orderFactory
    )
    {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {

        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load('1');


        $orderCommentHistory = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection();

      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($orderCommentHistory);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have `$order` object then you can easily get the order comment history by,

```
$order->getStatusHistoryCollection()
```

---

If you don't have `$order` object then you can use like this,

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory as OrderFactory;

protected $orderFactory;


public function __construct(
    ...
    OrderFactory $orderFactory  
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;    
    ....
}


$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load('YOUR_ORDER_ID');
$orderCommentHostory=$order->getStatusHistoryCollection();
```

**EDIT**
If you need order comment then please try this,

```
$orderComment = [];
foreach ($order->getStatusHistoryCollection() as $status) {
    if ($status->getComment()) {
        $orderComment[] = $status->getComment();
    }
}
```

At the end, you have all order comments in `$orderComment`

Comment: try to print `$orderCommentHistory->getData()`

Comment: Thanks for your response .I had given  $orderCommentHostory=$order->getData();  It shows all the order details of id 1 . But it is failed to fetch getStatusHistoryCollection().

Comment: Has this order any comments? Please check on backend @Jayashree

Comment: Yes. Now it works fine. Thnak you soo much. But i need only the comment field. How do i get it?

Comment: See my edit,  @Jayashree

Comment: Is it possible to get all the order comments without using id

Comment: @KeyurShah, how do I get specific order comment based on status? Suppose customer has canceled an order from store front and added a cancel reason. How do we get that cancel reason considering we have the `$order` object and how to make sure that customer is notified? For ex - `$order.getComment()`